# How to get free domain names for GWT APP?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am trying to add free domain using http://my.dot.tk/registration for a GWT ,Appengine hosted website.The free domin registrtion site is asking for A records, particularly IP address but I don't think GWT or appgengine is providing any IP address .What is my way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [register the domain with Google Apps](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3), then follow the steps they provide.  Once registered, you can go to `Domain Settings > Domain Names > Redirect your naked domain`, and they will provide you IPs to enter for your A records.

Then you can link your App Engine application with your domain through the App Engine dashboard.

Comment: Well, that way its asking for the domain I already own and I am just trying to register a free domain first,I don't own one yet.

Comment: You can't register the domain first, without setting the A records?  Then set them later?

Comment: register pointing to some placeholder page (they might let you get away with google.com/etc but better to make a free wordpress or blogger page or something, if you don't have anything else), and make sure to sign up for my.dot.tk. you'll be able to login later and change the dns settings